# XML deserialization with alias names

Tags: c#, deserialization

I have a method that returns a xml like so

```
<firstname>Jullian</firstname>
```

This is deserialized to a class

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "firstname")]
public class Firstname
{

    [XmlText]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the method signature

```
public Firstname GetFirstName();
```

There's another method which returns this xml

```
<first_name>Jullian</first_name>
```

Now my question is can I use the same class Firstname to deserialize the 2nd xml?
Is there a alias that can be provided to do this?

Regards.